# Why my Regex let me write "," (Comma)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript regex function code above:

```
function AcceptDigits(objtextbox) {
    var exp = /[^\d{1,3}]/g;
    objtextbox.value = objtextbox.value.replace(exp, '');
};
```

Always that I write a any special character the function remove this character for Example:

I write 45656654@ and this function clean the "@" like that 45656654.

**My problem**

The problem is that when I Write any "," (Comma) the function does not work, I try ".-()/&%$#" and the function work.

Any help to catch and remove the comma?

Comment: You shouldn't place `{1,3}` inside the set. Your regex could be rewritten as `/\D{1,3}/g`.

Comment: You're telling it to match anything that isn't a digit, {, 1, a comma, 3, or }. Inside a range (the square brackets) special characters aren't generally treated as special characters, they're treated as the regular character. What are the actual rules you're trying to enforce?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
/[^\d{1,3}]/g
```

means "a single character that is neither a digit, a curly brace nor a comma".

You probably meant

```
/\D{1,3}/g
```

but actually, if you want to use that regex to replace non-digits, just use

```
/\D+/g
```

Comment: Tim I'm sorry I was Confused, But I am using the `/\D+/g` but let me type curly bruce,  Do You know what is it Happen? Another question Why the function does not work in Chrome?

Comment: @Freak_Droid: Your function doesn't care what you type. It will *remove* all non-digits from the textbox when it's called.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation why the comma doesn't work:**

In square brackets (set of characters) most symbols don't have its special effects, except for `]` and `\` and `^` at the beginning of the set, which means complement. Therefore

```
[^\d{1,3}]
```

means *any character that is not number nor `{`, `1`, `,`, `3`, `}`* (`1` and `3`, is redundant info here).

**Further explanation:** `\d` means any number, `\D` means complement to number (everything but number), `[]` means set of characters. Since both `\d` and `\D` are already sets, there's no need to put them into square brackets and `[^\d]` is the same as `\D`.

Therefore to match everything but 1-3 numbers set, you may write `\D{1,3}` or `[^\d]{1,3}`. In other words, put the curly brackets behind the square brackets.

---

Tim Pietzckler in the other answer shows what you should do.

Comment: Well I read your explanation, I understand What's happened. Only I remove all inside `{}` and that Works `/[^\d{}]/g`, I dont know whether that is right or not but thanks.

Comment: @Freak_Droid: Well, no. Now curly braces will also be ignored by the replace operation, not just digits.

Comment: @TimPietzcker How I do Resolve It? Now I fell confuse :S thanks.

Comment: @Freak_Droid: see my updated answer, I tried to explain it as clearly as I could, if it is not clear, just comment, RegExps are tough stuff.

Comment: @JanTuroň Thanks for the Further explanation, was very helpfull. But look, Tim answered a regex `/\D+/g` this works very good but let me  type curly brace. why? And I said to him another question that Why the function does not work in Chrome? I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Freak_Droid really? try this: `alert("hi 42 {ho}".replace(/\D+/g,''));` the curly braces are out